# For Google Guava ImmutableLists is creating a copy of Collections.EMPTY_LIST equivalent to ImmutableList.of()?

Tags: java, collections, guava

Of these which one is preferred?

```
private static ImmutableList<Airline> sAirlines = 
                          ImmutableList.copyOf(Collections.EMPTY_LIST);

private static ImmutableList<Airline> sAirlines = ImmutableList.of();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want an empty immutable list, then you should use the 2nd approach. Because, for an empty collection, the `copyOf` method will anyway invoke `of()` method internally.

The `copyOf(Collection<? extends E>)` method internally uses the below method:

```
static <E> ImmutableList<E> asImmutableList(Object[] elements) {
    switch (elements.length) {
      case 0:
        return of();
      case 1:
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // collection had only Es in it
        ImmutableList<E> list = new SingletonImmutableList<E>((E) elements[0]);
        return list;
      default:
        return construct(elements);
    }
  }
```

As you can see, for length of `0`, it simply invokes `of()` method.

Comment: `of()` is also preferable because if you later change from empty to having one or more elements, it's simply a matter of adding those elements between the parentheses.